# fetchXml Dynamics 365 with sorting on link entity and paging working only for first page, not others

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-webapi

following query is working fine for first page

```
<fetch count="10" no-lock="true" page="1">
    <entity name="account">
        <attribute name="accountid" />
        <attribute name="name" />
        <link-entity name="contact" from="parentcustomerid" to="accountid" link-type="outer" alias="contact">
            <attribute name="contactid" />
            <attribute name="fullname" />
            <attribute name="jobtitle" />
            <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
            <attribute name="telephone1" />
            <attribute name="donotbulkemail" />
            <attribute name="donotphone" />
            <attribute name="telephone3" />
            <attribute name="mobilephone" />
            <attribute name="statuscode" />
            <attribute name="statecode" />
            <order attribute="lastname" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

the same query for second page gives only one record

```
<fetch count="10" no-lock="true" page="2">
    <entity name="account">
        <attribute name="accountid" />
        <attribute name="name" />
        <link-entity name="contact" from="parentcustomerid" to="accountid" link-type="outer" alias="contact">
            <attribute name="contactid" />
            <attribute name="fullname" />
            <attribute name="jobtitle" />
            <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
            <attribute name="telephone1" />
            <attribute name="donotbulkemail" />
            <attribute name="donotphone" />
            <attribute name="telephone3" />
            <attribute name="mobilephone" />
            <attribute name="statuscode" />
            <attribute name="statecode" />
            <order attribute="lastname" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

No idea, What is wrong with second and onward page request?

If I remove the `order attribute` from link entity then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a paging cookie? That will not work in this case, where there are multiple rows returned for each account.

> **[When not to use paging cookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/page-large-result-sets-with-fetchxml#when-not-to-use-paging-cookies)**
>
> Paging cookies depend on the common case where each row returned represents a unique entity record. There
>   are some queries you can construct using link-entity that will provide
>   rows that combine data from the primary entity with related entities.
>   This will result in multiple primary entity rows that refer to the
>   same primary key value. If you depend on paging cookies in this
>   situation you will get inconsistent results.

My preferred way to fix this issue is to "flip" your query around: Make contact your primary entity and link to account instead (presuming this would be a suitable query for you). Your query would then look as follows:

```
<fetch count="10" no-lock="true" page="1">
    <entity name="contact">
        <attribute name="contactid" />
        <attribute name="fullname" />
        <attribute name="jobtitle" />
        <attribute name="emailaddress1" />
        <attribute name="telephone1" />
        <attribute name="donotbulkemail" />
        <attribute name="donotphone" />
        <attribute name="telephone3" />
        <attribute name="mobilephone" />
        <attribute name="statuscode" />
        <attribute name="statecode" />
        <order attribute="lastname" />
        <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentcustomerid" link-type="outer" alias="account">
            <attribute name="accountid" />
            <attribute name="name" />
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: No, I am not using page cookies as displayed in question..Also cannot make contact primary as the result should contains account those does not have contact. :)

Comment: This is something strange behavior from dynamic API.